"Bet delta-tracking" - a feasible idea? How to avoid biasing the solution?
I wonder if it could be possible to do the usual (non-analog neutral particle) Monte Carlo delta-tracking, computing a small region of the problem in which a particle is emitted where the variation in $\sigma_t$ (total cross section) is smaller than in the whole problem, and in doing the usual delta-tracking on the particle history with a maximum $\sigma_t$ that is the local maximum in the small region, taking a bet that the particle will not stray beyond the boundaries of this small region. If the particle does stray its history could be carried over to the next domain or cancelled.
My question is, how would one correct the bias?
What I have tried includes the following.
(1) If choosing to carry over the computation to the new domain where the particle crossed, compute the ratio $R = \sigma_t/\sigma_{t, new}$ and update the particle's weight as new_weight = old_weight*R.
(2) If choosing to cancel the history rather than carrying the computation over in the next domain, add the cancelled particle's weight to the weight of the next new particle born in the same domain.
I have tried these two correction strategies and I get wrong results.
Why do at all "bet delta-tracking"? Well, to compute problems with large variations in total cross section which not only would converge slowly, but would also, from numerical experience, converge badly.
Can anyone suggest a solution?
